# Finding the image of an operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $T:\ell_{2} \rightarrow \ell_{2}$ be defined by

$$T(x) = \left(x_{1},\frac{x_{2}}{2},\frac{x_{3}}{4},\ldots,\frac{x_{n}}{2^{n-1}},\ldots \right)$$

where $x = (x_{1},x_{2},.....).$

Find $\text{Im}T$, the image of $T$.

I know that the kernel of this operator is $\{0\}$ and I know that
$$\dim\text{Im}T + \dim \ker T = \dim \ell_{2}$$
and  $\ker T^{\bot} = \ell_{2}$.

Then how can I complete, could anyone help me please?

Comment: $\text{Im}(T)=\{x\in\ell^2:\sum_k2^{k-1}|x(k)|^2<\infty\}$.

Comment: @Aweygan Almost...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right. Forgot a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
In general $$\mathrm{Im}(T)=\{y\in \ell^2|\exists\ x\in\ell^2\text{ with }Tx=y\}$$
Now, $$\ell^2=\left\{x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x(k)|^2<+\infty\right.\right\}$$
Can you now conclude to the solution given in the comments section from @Aweygan?

**Edit:** So, let
$$c_{00}=\{x\in\ell^2|\exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }\forall\ n>N\ x(n)=0\}$$
Now, let $y\in\mathrm{Im}(T)$. Then, there exists a $x\in\ell^2$ such that:
$$Tx=\left(x(1),\frac{x(2)}{2},\dots,\frac{x(n)}{2^{n-1}},\dots\right)=(y(1),y(2),\dots,y(n),\dots)$$
So, we have that:
$$\begin{align*}
x(1)&=y(1)\\
x(2)&=2y(2)\\
\vdots&=\vdots\\
x(n)&=2^{n-1}y(n)\\
\vdots&=\vdots
\end{align*}$$
Since both $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\ell^2$ we have that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x(n)|^2<\infty\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty|2^{n-1}y(n)|^2<\infty$$
So, we can easily verify that:
$$\mathrm{Im}(T)=\left\{y\in\ell^2\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|2^{n-1}y(n)\right|^2<\infty\right.\right\}$$

Let now $y\in c_{00}$. Then, there exists a $N=N(y)$ such that:
$$y=(y(1),y(2),\dots,y(N),0,\dots)$$
Consider now the sequence:
$$x=(y(1),2y(2),\dots,2^{N-1}y(N),0,\dots)$$
Then, evidently:
$$Tx=y$$
and both $x,y\in c_{00}\subseteq\ell^2$, so $y\in\mathrm{Im}(T)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, we have that:
$$c_{00}\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(T)$$
(wo have also proved that $T(c_{00})\subseteq c_{00}$, but this will not be needed for this proof).

Now, given that $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^2$, we have that:
$$\overline{c_{00}}=\ell^2$$
So, finally, due to closure's monotonicity:
$$\ell^2=\overline{c_{00}}\subseteq\overline{\mathrm{Im}(T)}\subseteq\ell^2\Rightarrow\overline{\mathrm{Im}(T)}=\ell^2$$

Comment: I think that the image is $sp\{e_{1}, e_{2},.....\}$..... but I have to prove that the closure of it is $l_{2}$ which means that this is the whole image of $T$ ..... this is my problem.....could you help me in doing so ?

Comment: Yu mean that you want to prove that $\mathrm{Im}(T)=\ell^2$?

Comment: yes but more precisely the closure of the image is $l^2$, if I am not having a mistake.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure and I'm not close to my PC now, but, could you prove that $c_{00}\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(T)$? Given that finally zeros sequences are dense in $\ell^2$ completes the proo, I think.

Comment: I will wait when you become close to your PC.

Comment: Why do you think the image is closed?

Comment: I think that my initial idea worked, finally - as you realised, it took me a long time to come close to my PC.